# Как передать в другую единицу трансляции имя символа?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Коротко резюмирую вопрос: Нужно получить адрес internal-linkage переменной из вне, то есть из другой единицы трансляции без геттеров. В файле, где определена internal-linkage переменная, есть функция, которая своим аргументом принимает, например, строковый литерал (имя переменной), и преобразует его в имя идентификатора (адрес internal-linkage переменной). Возможно ли провернуть такое?

Есть main.cpp и a.cpp

В a.cpp есть свои переменные с внутренним связыванием, доступные только в a.cpp и есть шаблонная функция со внешним связыванием, которая доступна во всех единицах трансляции. Эта шаблонная функция (в a.cpp) в качестве аргумента принимает одну из переменных с внутренним связыванием, определенных тоже в a.cpp.

Вопрос: как из main.cpp вызвать ту самую шаблону функцию и передать в качестве аргумента переменную с внутренним связыванием определенную в a.cpp? Нужно указать функции какой идентификатор взять в ее (функции) области видимости, а не файла main.cpp. Возможно ли такое? Адресов переменных мы не знаем, знаем только имена идентификаторов.

```
// main.cpp:
#include <iostream>
#include "common.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << boolalpha
         << (&n == &GetN()) // false
         << endl;

    cout << boolalpha
         << (&n == &GetT(n)) // true
         << endl;

    return 0;
}

// common.h:
const int n = 0;    // internal linkage

const int& GetN();  // external linkage

template<typename T>
T& GetT(T& t) {
    return t;
}


// a.cpp:
#include "common.h"

const int& GetN() {
    return n;
}
```

Нужно заменить (&n == &GetN()) на шаблонный аналог.
Шаблонная функция из примера выше работает неправильно, так как передает аргументом переменную n из текущей области видимости, а должна передавать n, определенную в файле a.cpp. Результат работы шаблонной функции в примере выше должен быть false.

Нужно что-то типа (&n == &GetT(a.cpp::n)). То есть, мы можем использовать только имя идентификатора, без функции взятия адреса в файле a.cpp

Comment: Ничего не мешает сделать `GetT( GetN() )`

Comment: я же написал - нужно передать именно имя идентификатора, без взятия адреса. и потом, шаблонная функцию как раз нужна для замещения GetN(), а не в дополнение к ней

Comment: В С++ нет рефлексии, обращаться к чему-либо по имени идентификатора нельзя. В вашем вопросе не демонстрируется, зачем понадобилось замещать `GetN` - ведь геттер является самым толковым вариантом для обращения к глобальной переменной. "нужно передать именно имя идентификатора" похоже на проблему xy.

Comment: user7860670, да, действительно, в моем вопросе не демонстрируется, зачем понадобилось замещать GetN. Один из возможных сценариев, только в качестве примера - представьте, что в common.h не одна переменная n, а десятки тысяч таких переменных, чьи адреса нужно сравнивать в разных единицах трансляции, вот поэтому вместо десятков тысяч геттеров в файле a.cpp хочется обойтись одной шаблонной функцией. Вопрос касается в большей степени  трюкачества и ловкачества, чем стандарта языка.

Comment: Если есть десятки тысяч таких переменных, то первым делом от них надо избавиться... *"Вопрос касается в большей степени трюкачества и ловкачества"* - ну тогда ответ будет заключаться в том, чтобы не прибегать ни к какому трюкачеству и ловкачеству.

Comment: Смахивает на [проблему XY](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-xy).

Comment: imho это принципиально невозможно. Шаблонная функция транслируется с подстановками текущего языкового контекста, который представлен одним компилируемым файлом (полученным после всех макроподстановок). Не меняя компилятор, вы не можете представить ему контекст из других файлов

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Короткий ответ на мой собственный вопрос "можно ли превратить строковый литерал в имя символа?" - нет, нельзя, потому что C++ статически типизирован, и это противоречит всей этой парадигме.

Answer (score 0):

Свяжите статическую переменную обычной ссылкой в нужном пространстве имён. И тогда можете уверенно достучаться до нужной  статической переменной извне.

common.h

```cpp
namespace acpp {
  // ссылается на статическую переменную в файле a.cpp
  extern  int const & n ;
}
```

a.cpp

```cpp
namespace acpp {
  // ссылка указывает на именно текущую статическую
  int const & n = :: n ;
}
```

И в `main.cpp` уже вы точно получите ссылку на нужную статику

```cpp
  cout << boolalpha
    << (&n == &GetT(acpp :: n)) // false
    << endl;
```

Comment: AlexGlebe, Ваше решение, безусловно, интересное, но по количеству кода оно ничем не уступает добавлению геттера для каждой переменной. Мне нужно провернуть такой трюк, чтобы получить адрес internal-linkage переменной из другой единицы трансляции, передав имя идентификатора в шаблонную функцию как, например, строковый литерал, а функция, приняв этот строкой литерал, смогла бы его использовать как имя идентификатора.

Comment: ...и, кстати, можно спокойно обойтись и без namespace, если ссылка имеет внешнее связывание, просто имя ссылки использовать другое, n_ref например

Answer (score 0):

Для связи строки и параметра можно схитрить разными способами.
Хочу показать один из.

Допустим у нас есть обработчик

```
void AddPropertyHandler(void * MyProp, const char * name) {
   // Тут мы уложим  MyProp в списочек красиво и инициализируем
  }
```

А как бы теперь так сделать.... что бы список свойств упал в этот список... А можно... Давайте создадим интересный шаблон

```
template <typename T,char... Chars> class MYT{
T value;
// Далее нужно реализовать implicit и explicit cast, реализовал один из
T& operator = (T val) {  value = val; return value; }; 
// Дальше реализуем конструктор, именно конструктор нам и поможет соиденить
 public: 
    MYT() { /*constructor*/                     
      const char name[sizeof...(Chars)+1] = {Chars...,'\0'}; // Поучаем имя
      AddPropertyHandler(this, name);  // Делаем проброс      
    }           
 };
```

Теперь.... создаём класс и добавляем N

```
 class MyClass { 
     public:
       MYT<int,"n"> n;  // Упростить можно через #define разве что
       MYT<int,"a"> a;
       MYT<int,"b"> b;
      }
```

Доп хитрость.

```
MYT<int,"n"> n;
```

упрощается так

```
#define D_MYT(x,n) MYT<x,#n> n;
```

Тогда можно переписать

```
 class MyClass { 
     public:
        D_MYT(int,n)
        D_MYT(int,a)
        D_MYT(int,b)
      }
```

Класс обязательно нужно создавать конструктором, тогда в AddPropertyHandler попадут все свойства с именами. Так же используя template можно разделить по-типам.

---

Так же можно применять такие штуки

```
 #define xdef_htmtag(a,b) const int _htag_##a=b;  const char* htmltag_##a=#a;

 xdef_htmtag(a,1);
 // const int _htag_a = 1;
 // const char*  htmltag_a = "a";
```

Возможно я угадал вашу мысль.

Answer (score -1):

Если нужно сравнивать адреса переменных (в контексте разных единиц трансляции), то нужно чтобы переменные имели внешнее связывание.

Получить адрес internal-linkage переменной, можно только изнутри соответствующей единицы трансляции. Снаружи - никак. Адреса этих переменных вообще не фигурируют в .obj файле, что развязывает руки оптимизатору.

Добиться внешнего связывания для констант можно двумя способами:

1. либо, явно объявив переменную внешней:

```
// a.h
extern const int n/*=0*/;
// a.cpp
const int n=0;
```

это не позволит использовать заранее известное значение переменной в оптимизациях или при вычислении размера статического массива...

2. Либо, объявить переменную inline, тогда при линвковке будет выбран адрес только одной переменной, как это делается с inline функциями, когда мы берем их адрес (требует C++17):

```
// a.h
inline const int n=0;
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но вся фишка как раз в том, чтобы получить адрес internal-linkage переменной из вне, из другой единицы трансляции без геттеров. С external переменными никаких проблем не возникает и вопрос теряет смысл. Была мысль, что можно каким-то замысловатым образом передать имя идентификатора как, например, строковый литерал, а функция, приняв этот строкой литерал, смогла его использовать как имя идентификатора.